# Inserting data to mysql ? One by one or the data as a whole which one is the better way to do it?

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

I am a beginner in programming and please excuse me if the question is stupid.

See the code below. It takes two values from a csv file named headphones_master_data.csv ( price, link) and writes the data into a MySQL table. When writing the data , the date is also being written to the table.

There are 900 rows in the file.  When you see the writing part, the  my_cursor.execute(sql, val) function is executed 900 times (the number of rows).

It got me thinking and I wanted to see if there are other ways to improve the data writing part. I came up with two ideas and they are as follows.

1 - Convert all the lists ( price, link)  into a dictionary and write the dictionary. So the my_cursor.execute(sql, val) function is executed just once.

2 - Convert the lists into a data frame and write that into the database so the write happens just once.

Which method is the best one? Are there any drawbacks of writing the data only once. More importantly, Am I thinking about the optimization correctly?

''''

```
import pandas as pd

import pymysql


data = pd.read_csv("headphones-master_data.csv") #read csv file and save this into a variable named data

link_list = data['Product_url'].tolist()  #taking athe url value from the data vaiable and turn into a list

price_list = data['Sale_price'].tolist()

crawled_date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #generate the date format compatiable with MySQL

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                         user='root',
                         password='passme123@#$',
                         db='hpsize')   #connection obhect to pass the database details


my_cursor = connection.cursor() #curser object to communicate with database


for i in range(len(link_list)):

    link = link_list[i]

    price = price_list[i]



    sql = "INSERT INTO comparison (link, price, crawled_date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" #sql query to add data to database with three variables

    val = link , price , crawled_date  #the variables to be addded to the SQL query


    my_cursor.execute(sql, val)  #execute the curser obhect to insert the data

    connection.commit() #commit and make the insert permanent


my_cursor.execute("SELECT * from comparison") #load the table contents to verify the insert

result = my_cursor.fetchall()

for i in result:
    print(i)

connection.close()
```

''''

Comment: It is MUCH faster to load a CSV file via `LOAD DATA INFILE ...`

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my opinion is to pass the data into a DataFrame and then use the .to_sql method in order to save the data in your MySQL database.
This method take an argument (method='multi') which allows you to insert all the data in the DataFrame in one go and within a very short time.. This works if your database allows multi-writing.
Read more here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. what if the number of rows is a lot more than 900, say 9 million. Would the same method be efficient in that case? And why exactly is the dictionary writing method least efficient than the data frame writing method?

Comment: Looks like pymysql doesn't support data frame to SQL

Comment: Use SQLAlchemy and psycopg2 they will work properly with the to_mysql. 
For very large dataset, you can use chucksize arguments